# Points Format in examclass -- add time

Tags: exam, points

I have been trying to find a way to add time per question within the points option (so that each question shows [X points, Y mins.] but I still have no idea how.

Is there any way to add a second optional argument, for example to the question command, so that the time per question is included automatically after the points?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\pointname{\%}
\bracketedpoints
\bonuspointpoints{point, min}{points, mins}

\newcommand{\timedpoints}[1]{\bonuspointpoints{point, #1 min}{points, #1 mins}}
\newcommand{\timedquestion}[3]{\timedpoints{#3}\bonusquestion[#1] #2}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\timedquestion{25}{Who painted ``La Gioconda''?}{2}
    \begin{checkboxes}
        \choice Pablo Picasso
        \choice Vincent van Gogh
        \CorrectChoice Leonardo da Vinci
        \choice Andy Warhol
    \end{checkboxes}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]